Get test Surface to show up in react native expo module
So I'm trying to create a native view for a RN project I have and I'm having a difficult time getting the test surface to show up in the project. Wondering what I might be doing wrong.
I have 3 files in my android projects folder
ExpoWebview.kt
ExpoWebViewModule.kt
TestForm.kt
My ExpoWebview.kt file looks like this:
package expo.modules.webview

import android.content.Context
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import expo.modules.kotlin.AppContext
import expo.modules.kotlin.views.ExpoView

class ExpoWebView(context: Context, appContext: AppContext) : ExpoView(context, appContext) {
//  internal val webView = WebView(context).also {
//    it.layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
//    it.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {}
//    addView(it)
//
//    it.loadUrl("https://docs.expo.dev/modules/")
//  }

  internal val composeView = ComposeView(context).also {
    it.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    it.setContent { TestForm() }
    addView(it)
  }
}

And my TestForm.kt file looks like this:
package expo.modules.webview
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun TestForm() {
    Surface (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(),
    ) {
        Card() {
            TextField(
                value = "Value",
                onValueChange = { /*TODO*/ },
            )
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp)
            )
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Click me!")
            }
        }
    }
}

When I toggle the WebView code to uncommented it shows the provided url so I know that the module is wired up corrrectly. However, when I comment out the WebView and put the TestForm composable in my screen goes blank when rebuilt.
Any idea why the composable isn't showing up?
